# Div always remains in center of parent div when ordering around it changes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achieve a layout like the following:

[image]

However, I'm struggling to keep the `.date` always centered when the alignment of the `.content` changes (i.e. if it's left of the date or right).

Here's my current approach:

```css
.timeline {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.timeline__item {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.timeline__item .content__first {
  order: 1;
}
.timeline__item .date__second {
  order: 2;
}
.timeline__item .content__second {
  order: 2;
}
.timeline__item .date__first {
  order: 1;
}
.timeline__item .date {
  padding: 0px 25px;
}
.timeline__item .content {
  max-width: 45%;
}
.timeline__item .content p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="timeline">

  <div class="timeline__item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center ">
    <div class="date date__first">
      <span class="date text-center">2018</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content content__second text-left ">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="timeline__item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center ">
    <div class="date date__second">
      <span class="date text-center">2016</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content content__first text-right ">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Is my markup correct for this approach? Each new `timeline__item` generated a new "row", so `.date` and `.content`. I cannot change the markup so that all `.date`'s are in one `div`. What's the best approach for this?

Comment: Without **fixed widths** - this is not possible - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972830/is-there-a-way-to-center-one-of-the-flex-grid-childrenmore-than-three-and-with

Comment: you can move the classes up to the row and use a pseudo element to create the gaps: https://www.bootply.com/9bYhF8CFok