# Center div based on child element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have three buttons inside a wrapper. As you may see in the snippet, the middle one is medium-sized, while the one in the left is wider and the right one is the smallest. I also have in this wrapper a title, which is aligned in the center.

What I'm trying to achieve is to align the buttons (in this case `.btns` div) based on the middle button, the medium-sized one. I want that button to be in the center, aligned with the title.

Here is a picture of what I would like the buttons to be aligned:

[image]

Although a CSS-only solution is preferable, I'm willing to use JS if needed.

How can I do that?

```css
#content {
  background: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

#title {
  padding-top: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.btns > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#b2 {
 margin: auto 15px auto 15px;
}

.btns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
  <div class="btns">
    <a href="#">Button Large</a>
    <a id="b2" href="#">B Med</a>
    <a href="#">B S</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55393088/align-3-unequal-blocks-left-center-and-right

Comment: Do you want out like this : https://jsfiddle.net/paqs0kjL/3/ ?

Comment: @AbhishekPakhare not actually, I was looking for all the three buttons on the same row. You can see what I mean on the photo in the original question. Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Comment: So according to the image you want your middle button under the TITLE and aligned center.right? Also does the size of the buttons need to be equal or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question is why you would want this behaviour ?

You can achieve that in multiple different ways, one of them would be to use grid. That will work but from a design standpoint this is not a really pleasing pattern unless your use case really justify this.

[Test pen link](https://codepen.io/simon-renault/pen/mdyMpOK)

```
#content {
  background: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

#title {
  padding-top: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.btns{
  display:grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

.btns > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.b1{
  text-align: right;
}
```

Hope this solves your problem !

Comment: Thanks! It is not perfect but way better than what I had. Regarding your question, I was trying to do this because when I first tried with the normal alignment it was a little odd, didn't feel right, you know.

Answer (score -1):

You should use flexbox for this.

```
display: flex; 
flex-direction: row; 
justify-context: center; 
align-items:center;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Answer (score -2):

If the middle link should always be in the center, then you can set `flex: 0 0 auto` on it and `flex: 1 1 0` on other 2.