# How to vertically centre the first child and the second child follows the flow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container which has 2 divs. I'm looking to vertically centre the first div and the second div to sit beneath it following the natural flow. See attached image.
[image: container]

I'm currently centring it by adding padding top to the first div through "container height - the first div height / 2" Is there another way I can achieve this?

Comment: related:https://stackoverflow.com/a/55393886/8620333 <-- you change the direction from row to column and you remove the first child

Comment: Anycode to share? Is this a single container with 2 children ? Is there a fixed height, are you using some kind of display alike grid,flex,table, else ?

Comment: ... while waiting for feed back, here is a grid possibility: https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jOmwWJN have fun