# How to center second item in a three item container that is fluid

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

How can I center the "to" div?

The red line is the center of the `bg-emerald-50` div. (I messed up when adding the red line, it's 20-30 pixels off but you get the point.)

**Important!** The items in the `bg-blue-200` div can vary from 1 to 5 items.

This is the markup I have so far:

```
  <div className="flex h-16 items-center justify-between bg-emerald-50">
    <div className="bg-teal-200">Hello</div>
    <div className="bg-orange-300">to</div>
    <div className="flex bg-blue-200 text-2xl">
      <div className="bg-pink-500">div1</div>
      <div className="bg-amber-200">div2</div>
      <div className="bg-lime-200">div3</div>
      <div className="bg-indigo-200">div4</div>
      <div className="bg-fuchsia-200">div5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

One approach is to absolute position the "to" div but that seems a bit hacky.

There is a similar post here [Align 3 unequal blocks left, center and right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55393088/align-3-unequal-blocks-left-center-and-right) but that one does not have an inner div!

Comment: As your picture shows, the red line is not in the center of `bg-emerald-50` =)) and IMHO there's nothing hacky with absolute positioning in your case.

Comment: haha you're right, realized that now :D
Updating post..

Comment: Please avoid profanity when posting here

Comment: This is what we all think ;) That's why I put an asterisk in place of the 'u'. But it's all good! ;)

Comment: Why is it still closed?

Comment: @PussInBoots, implied profanity isn't welcome here any more than explicit profanity. And it's still closed because not enough users have voted to reopen it. From my perspective, it still looks like this is a duplicate question.

Comment: As I said, it's not a dupe. I checked. The other solution has spans instead of an inner div - completely different markup structure.

Comment: @PussInBoots, well if three users (or one gold CSS badge holder) agree with you your question can be reopened. Be patient. (You don't get to arbitrarily declare that your question is unique when it's been closed as a dupe.)

Comment: I know. And it's fine. But like I said, it's not a dupe and should be reopened. Now I'm loosing all the first people and probably the ones that most likely were willing to help because the question got closed prematurely.

Comment: Your question *is* a duplicate. I gave the answer in the duplicate target and your markup is not different. 3 elements inside a flexbox container

Comment: It's not. And I think you're doing the community a disservice. But you can go ahead and delete the question. I already solved it.

Comment: @PussInBoots, I'm not a CSS expert so can't say for sure whether it's a dupe or not, but it looks like it to me. Two gold-badged CSS users agree that it is. Maybe you don't understand what we mean by "duplicate". Dupes don't have to be _exact, drop-in replacements_. If the fundamental question is the same and a few details are different, it might be a dupe. If the details are irrelevant, it _is_ a dupe. The idea is to read the duplicate question and its answers and apply them to your own, possibly slightly different, situation. I think that applies here.